# Using infinity.js with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, infinity.js

I'm implementing a long list of contacts on the page and would like to use infinity.js library for smooth scrolling.

Can someone share jsfiddle ideally with some snippets to implement it?
I believe it can be done using directives, but I'm very new to Angular.

I found this [jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/1zN8XxG), but I don't think it works properly...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it isn't working properly

Comment: Checkout http://airbnb.github.io/infinity/demo-on.html. Content is paged on the page, whereas on that jsfiddle everything loaded contiguously. Moreover, there are errors in console regarding infinity.js

Comment: The infinityjs external resource just needs to be updated http://cdnjs.com/libraries/infinity